# font heart symbols are the wrong color when run through phonegap build

Tags: fonts, colors, phonegap-build, symbols

I'm trying to include red heart symbols (♥) in my app (color:#800000 in my CSS). They appear properly in a Chrome browser on a desktop but when I pass the code through Phonegap and run it on my (Android) phone, they come out black. If I put standard text inside the span along with the hearts, the text comes out red but not the hearts.

I tried both the native font element (U+2663 in the Arial character map) and the html version `&hearts;` and it happens with both.

If anyone knows how to correct this, it would be appreciated. I'm open to workarounds as well, though I'm trying to avoid using actual heart images.

Comment: this video [(The Android Webview | PhoneGap Day EU 2015 )](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mP6rhbDT0ZQ) is worth watching. It indirectly talks about your issue. The speaker's native language is not English, so he is a little slow. Bottom, you might need to move to crosswalk, if this is a show stoper.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I've already been running into that general problem, most notably when my phone upgraded to Android 5.

This was literally one of the last details left to wrap this up, so I'm hesitant to move to another platform for this one thing just yet. Good to know that it's an option.